# Casting a subclass object to superclass reference in RMI

Tags: java, serialization, interface, polymorphism, rmi

I have a question involving RMI, Serialization and runtime polymorphism.

I have an RMI server with below:

```
public interface Shape extends Remote, Serializable { 
    public double getArea() throws RemoteException;
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
  double radius;
  public Circle( double r) { radius = r; }
  public double getArea() { return Math.PI * radius * radius; }
}
```

An object `cObj` of Circle class is registered in the RMI Registry:

```
Circle cObj = new Circle (10);
registry.bind("cObj", cObj);
```

Now, on the client side, I have the Shape.class file on the CLASSPATH, but it does not have Circle.class file on CLASSPATH.
Is it possible for the RMI client to perform below?

```
Shape obj = (Shape) registry.lookup("cObj");
obj.getArea();
```

Note that Circle.class is not in the CLASSPATH of the RMI client and the code on the client is not directly referencing the Circle class anyway. It is only referencing Shape interface type.

How I would look at this, may be the client performs a lookup and finds the object with cObj name, and Circle type. The server knows that Circle is a subtype of Shape, and serializes the object and sends it to the client. Now, I am not sure if the client can cast it into the superclass (Shape) type without having access to the Circle class definition.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it? The best way to answer these sorts of questions is to set up a simple test and actually try it. It looks like you have some valid code. Test it!

Comment: thanks. seems to work with Shape type, but doesnt work with Circle type. Couldnt post the answer due to restrictions on new joinees. I will post complete code and observations tomorrow.

Comment: It won't ever work with Circle if what you mentioned is true: "without having access to the Circle class definition". If the client only knows about Shape, it will never be able cast it to a circle object. I am actually surprised it works at all, even just casting it to the Shape interface.

Comment: I meant, " 'the client' without having access to the Circle class definition". Basically, the client doesnt know about Circle object. It knows only about Shape class. When it invokes the getArea() method, it is making an RMI call to server and the server invokes the getArea() method of Circle. The result is sent back to client and the client feels like it had invoked getArea() method on Shape. It is extending the concept of "Interface as API" in distributed environment. You can distribute Shape interface to your clients, and add new implementations of different shapes on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deploy the Circle class to the client you have two choices:

1. Use the RMI codebase feature. You need to look this up as it is far too large a topic to discuss here, but basically it makes classloading possible from an additional location dictated by the RMI server.
2. Make it an exported remote object, so that calls to it are also RMI calls. You're halfway there already by making Shape extended Remote, but you also need to export Circle, either by making it extend UnicastRemoteObject or by calling UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject() with it on construction.

It seems to me that by extending Remote you really meant to do (2) all along. If you do this you don't need to make Shape extend Serializable. If you *don't* do (2) there is no point in having Shape extend Remote. You should remove one or the other: they are kind of mutually exclusive.

Comment: thanks. I tried the implementation test, and yes I went with approach (2), as I wanted to check whether a remote client can invoke methods (overriden of courese) of Circle object without actually having the definition of Circle class. It seems, it can. Though, one peculiar observation with the line :
    Shape stub = (Shape) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(cObj, 0);

is that I cant do like below:
    Circle stub = (Circle) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(cObj, 0);

It gives compile error on the server. look at full code that I have posted. btw, thanks for the tip about Remote & Serializable.

Comment: @Pratik Of course you can't. The result of exportObject isn't the original object, it's an RMI stub implementing the same remote interface, in this case Shape. See the Javadoc. So you can cast it to Shape, but not to Circle. If Circle has an extended API that you want exposed to clients you need to make Circle an interface that extends Shape, and change the name of the present Circle class to say CircleImpl, CircleServer, etc.